# Make [privileges] a tag synonym of [permissions]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I propose to make [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/privileges) a synonym of [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions).

The synonym is already officially suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/tags/permissions/synonyms). If you meet the requirements, you can vote on the suggestion depending on whether you agree or not:

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Some stats about the two tags:

---

**[permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions)**

- 3487 questions
- 41 followers
- Excerpt:

  > Short for "file system permissions" - access control based on user, group, or global access.
- Wiki: *none*

---

**[privileges](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/privileges)**

- 109 questions
- 2 followers
- Excerpt:

  > same as permissions "file system permissions" - access control based on user, group, or global access.
- Wiki:

  > [image]
  >
  > **rwx**, stand for = [**r**]ead | [**w**]rite | [**x**]execute - privileges, that can be either given/added `+` or taken away `-`
  >
  > **There are tree groups**:
  >
  > - Owner - `u`
  > - Group - `g`
  > - Other/Everybody Else - `o`
  > - ALL OF THEM - `a`

Comment: Instead of synonyms is better to merge them into a [file-permission] tag, since this has nothing to do with "file permissions" [Make default user to be root](http://askubuntu.com/q/799502)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mission accomplished.

https://askubuntu.com/tags/permissions/synonyms

> The following tags will be remapped to [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions):
>
> [root-permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/root-permission), [rights](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rights) and [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/privileges)